# Second CV Journal Club question about the raw data that was selected

Tags: discussion, journal-club, papers, data-mining

Does anyone know where the "list of trees" is published for the tree ring data used in the analysis for the upcoming paper. I have played around with some of the controversial stuff (for instance, tree YAD061 and other "Yamal trees"), but so far, I haven't found a reliable source that lists the trees they kept and those they ditched when they generated the series.

I have the same question about the borehole temperature data and whatever else they used.

Edit (01/20/2011) ==============================

Here's a better description of what I'm looking for.

I realize that what is about to be discussed is the analysis/processing of the "incoming data".   However, a second issue is the "incoming data" itself, and can I (a mere mortal) duplicate what the authors have done?

Here's an example:

First, something part of, or similar to the "incoming data":

http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/people/briffa/yamal2009/sensit.htm

Figure A shows their "hockey stick".  Then there's a description of the "Regional Curve Standardisation", then a map showing the location of the trees, and believe it or not, an actual description of the raw data that was used.   The data sets are at:

http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/people/briffa/yamal2009/data/

Such that if you want to fool with the data for a specific tree, you can.   For example, I can download and play with tree YAD061 (from 1803 to 1996):

http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/people/briffa/yamal2009/data/YAD_RAW.txt

My goal is to understand what the authors did so I can get an idea of how reasonable the "incoming data" really is.

Comment: Thanks for moving the question to meta. I've just deleted your original question from the main site.